# Cannot fix ajax asp.net and jquery conflict

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, ajax

I have blinking text modal dialog box and slideshow with jquery. They working just great. But when im clicking my button this (slideshow, blinking, dialog box) stops working . This conflict started when i inserted my asp:ScriptManager and asp:UpdatePanel in my master page

I have multiple jquery files in my project. Yesterday googled this problem and find solution. I edited this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

With THis

```
function pageLoad() {
```

Now problem is that if i will use this in all my jquery files. Every scripts will stops working.

THis is how my buttons looks like:

```
 <input type="button" id="btnReset" class="default_button" value="Reset" runat="server"
            onserverclick="btnReset_Click" />
```

Im getting this worning in javascript console:

```
 Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined
```

P.s i inserted ScriptManager, UpdatePanel, ContentTemplate bellow `form`(masters page) so all my page is inside this tags even content place holder

Please somebody im trying to fix it already 5 days.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Script  Manager and jQuery together without any problems.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

works perfectly. What was the conflict you had?

Comment: Does it possible that conflict occurs in jquery files not in asp.net ajax. Conflict i had is that they dont work after button click which uses code behind

Comment: There is likely something else wrong here. What happens if you click the button? If you use chrome you can debug javascript. Or Firebug.

Comment: Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined. << this is worning which i m getting on button click

Comment: This totally does not sound like a Javascript Error. What happens if you debug it in Chrome?